# including List/ArrayList items in JList doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, list, arraylist, jlist

I'm having this problem today that I can't figure out how to solve. I know it's probably something stupid that I'm overlooking, but it's been hours already....
So,

I have my class, that extends JPanel. Inside I have just a scrollpane with a jlist. This class receives a List to use to populate the JList. The List contains several "Orcamento" which is one of  my program classes. The class has a .toString method.
I have tried using models, and creating the JList directly with the list using .toArray. I've tried transforming the List in ArrayList and doing the same. I tried using `DefaultListModel<String>` and `DefaultListModel<Orcamento>`.

Hope you can help me with this.

Here's some code:
The JPanel

```
package Views;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import Models.Orcamento;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;

public class OrcamentoView extends JPanel {

    private JList lista;
    private DefaultListModel modelo;
    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public OrcamentoView(List<Orcamento> lst) {
        setBounds(0, 21, 434, 241);
        setLayout(null);
        
        ArrayList<Orcamento> orcs= new ArrayList(lst);
        DefaultListModel<String> modelo = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        for(Orcamento o:orcs)
            modelo.addElement(o.toString());
        lista = new JList();
        lista.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        lista.setModel(modelo);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(lista);
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 219);
        add(scrollPane);
    }
}
```

After finishing the JPanel I do:

```
public void setContent(JPanel menu, JPanel content){
        contentPane.removeAll();
    contentPane.add(menu);
        contentPane.add(content);
    contentPane.repaint();
}
```

to add the panel to my JFrame.(Which I've been doing with many other panels).

Answer (score 2):

you have forgotten?

```
add(lista);
```

Comment: isn't it implied in "JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(lista);"?

Comment: like this...  JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();  
sp.getViewport().setView(lista);  
sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 80));